# How to eliminate race condition in reporting progress from loop in an asynchronous function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to report progress from an asynchronous function according to the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Blah();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void Blah()
        {
            var ProgressReporter = new Progress<int>(i => Console.WriteLine(i + "%"));
            await Foo(ProgressReporter);
        }

        static Task Foo(IProgress<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 100 == 0)
                    {
                        onProgressPercentChanged.Report(i / 100);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However, as `i` keeps getting updated, before it can be printed, the output is messed up. Example Output:

```
1%
3%
0%
4%
5%
6%
8%
7%
9%
2%
```

My belief was that the IProgress interface aims to eliminate such race conditions by awaiting any lambda expressions or methods to be executed when the progress is updated. Am I missing anything which would eliminate this race condition?

Comment: I don't see place where "as `i` keeps getting updated, before it can be printed..." - can you show the sample that can be compiled/run?

Comment: @Alexei `i` is updated in the for loop of the Foo method, whereas it is printed by the lambda expression passed to the constructor of the `Progress<T>` object (`ProgressReporter`). I have updated the code so that it can be compiled and Run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because the callback is being run on a thread.

Why?

The Console application.

According to the `Progress` class MSDN documentation:

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed. If there is no current SynchronizationContext at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the ThreadPool.

Essentially, your callbacks are out of whack because there is no `SynchronizationContext` in a Console application.. so they are being fired on ThreadPool threads.

Try it in a Windows application.. here's a screenshot of the output for the exact same code:

[image: Sync example]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in a WPF application and it worked due to the SynchronizationContext being present as you explained.

Comment: And because there is no work being done, all progress reports happen almost at the same time. Just insert some work (longer than the time it take to report the progress) and you'll see a diferente output.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I'm aware of that. I was just trying out the bare loop as a worst case scenario since all work may not last longer than the time taken to report the progress.

Answer (score 4):

First - there is not  "as `i` keeps getting updated, before it can be printed..." code:

- Variables inside your `for` loop and delegate are completely unrelated.
- There is no lambda passed to `.Report` that could have captured `i` - [Report(T value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `int` in your case and have no way to report different value.

You can convince yourself that by changing variable names to be different.

Second: reporting is fine, but notifications received in random order (explained by Simon Whitehead answer)

You can easily see that values reported are correct by adding console trace to the task:

```
      onProgressPercentChanged.Report(i / 100);
      Console.WriteLine("--" + i + "%");
```

Side note: normally you'd write `async` function with `async`:

```
static async Task Foo(IProgress<int> onProgressPercentChanged)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                onProgressPercentChanged.Report(i / 100);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this begs the question: How to initialize a SynchronizationContext for a console application? I am using this answer titled:

### Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps

> The continuations used by the remainder of the async method’s execution would have been
>   posted to SynchronizationContext.Current, except that it a console
>   app, it’s null (unless you explicitly override that with
>   SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext).

The article goes on to show you how to write and setup a synchronizationContext in a console app

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx

Peace out of your head and into your heart.